# How do I Include Nested Quotes HTML?

Tags: jquery, html

How do I property include quotes in a string? I want to do something like this:

```
var stringvariable;
$('#somediv').append('<a href id="someid" + onclick="doSomething("'+stringvariable+'")> MyLink"+</a>');
```

The problem has to do with the following part: 
`onclick="doSomething("'+stringvariable+'")`

How do I allow nested double quote since I need to be able to do:
`onclick="doSomething("stringvalue")"`

Answer (score 6):

You can escape the quotes within the string using back slashes `\`:

```
var stringvariable;
$('#somediv').append('<a href id="someid" + onclick="doSomething(\''+stringvariable+'\')> MyLink"+</a>');
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use escapes to accomplish this, but for legibility, I'd suggest doing:

```
$('#somediv')
    .append('<a href id="someid">MyLink</a>')
    .click(function() {
       doSomething(stringvariable);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use single qoutes instead.

```
onclick="doSomething('stringvalue')"
```

Comment: He can't without escaping them, because the original string is enclosed within single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQuery, use it throughout. The following would be better and easier to maintain:

```
var $a = jQuery("<a></a>")
    .attr("id", "someid")
    .attr("href", "http://example.com")
    .text("My Link")
    .click(function() {
   doSomething("stringvalue");
});
jQuery("#somediv").append($a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript uses both `'` and `"` as string delimiters so use this to your advantage.

```
onclick="doSomething('value');"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
onclick="doSomething(\"stringvalue\")";
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this alternate method? Will accomplish what you're trying to do and should hopefully prove a bit more readable:

```
var stringVariable = "foo";

$('<a/>', 
    { id: "someid", 
      text: "MyLink"
    } 
 ).click( function() { doSomething(stringVariable) } )
  .appendTo("#somediv");
```